# Rspec returns syntax error of "unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end"

Tags: ruby, rspec

This works on one machine with Ruby but not another.

Code:

```
describe 'testing reverse string different ways' do

  let :thing {'cba321'}

  it 'the system method' do
    source = '123abc'
    result = source.reverse
    expect(result).to eq 'cba321'
  end 
end
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError:                                                                                                             
  /home/michael/Dropbox/90_2019/work/code/ruby__rails/ruby/reverse_string_tests_timing/test_spec.rb:12: syntax error, une
xpected '{', expecting keyword_end                                                                                       
    let :thing {'cba321'}                                                                                                
               ^                                                                                                         
  /home/michael/Dropbox/90_2019/work/code/ruby__rails/ruby/reverse_string_tests_timing/test_spec.rb:12: syntax error, une
xpected '}', expecting end-of-input                                                                                      
    let :thing {'cba321'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby `2.4.1` not having parens in the let was allowed but in Ruby `2.5.1` it is not.

So the fix is to add parens to the `let`, e.g.

change

```
let :source {'cba321'}
```

to

```
let (:source) {'cba321'}
```

Comment: `let(:source) { .... }` would be better so that the parentheses really are method-calling parentheses.

Comment: It's also considered good style practice to have spaces inside braces. A "nicely" formatted line would be `let(:source) { 'cba321' }`.